# Wordpress redirectioning to localhost

Tags: wordpress

I installed the WAMP and WordPress in a PC to test it. I can access through the URL `localhost/test` and it works. The IP of this PC is `10.0.0.150`.

I tried access my site of the other PC using the URL `10.0.0.150/test` and I am redirecting to `localhost/test` (but I am not localhost in the other machine).

I click Panel > Settings> General >

The fields `Site Address (URL)` and `WordPress Address (URL)` are filled with `localhost/test`

How I fix it?

Sorry my bad English ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are so many possibilities in your case...

Check your database, there is URL being stored in DB which need to replace

```
from localhost/test to 10.0.0.150/test
```

You can replace it by [DATABASE SEARCH AND REPLACE SCRIPT IN PHP](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/)

Just put folder into your localhost and run through browser, and you can replace all URL from DB.

Another check is your local wamp server should access by IP for that,

```
Go to C:\WAMP\bin\apache\apache2.2.17\conf (version may change)
Open httpd.conf file in notepad.
Find the section given below. By default it will be like this.

<Directory "c:/wamp/www/">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride all
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Directory>>
Now change this section as given below.

<Directory "c:/wamp/www/">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride all
Order Deny,Allow
#Deny from all
#Allow from 127.0.0.1
Allow from all
</Directory>
Restart apache service.
```

Further you can create virtual host via httpd.conf and share it into internal server as well.

Answer (score 1):

Probably your IP adress or your port are set differently on the other machine. You set your localhost in Wamp first, after you put same setting in Worpress.

Wamp emulate server on your computer. It must having same settings. In wamp usualy, by default, directory wamp/www is the localhost, so you must save your test directory there. In Wordpress, just set it as localhost/test, forget 10.0.0.150, that can change. Wordpress asking you URL, so just give him URL, not the IP adress. Be sure your port is set to 80 (default) in Wamp and close skype. Skype use port 80 by default too.

If you set another port than 80 in Wamp, you will be oblige to set everything as localhost:portNumber/test and in addition, you will be oblige to type the samething in your browser adress bar, to reach your site.

I hope it will help you.